# Problem with crawling Oracle portal with SharePoint Server 2007 Search

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office

We got "No Index Attribute" error when we try to indexing Oracle Portal from SharePoint Server 2007 Search crawler. The content source is added successfully. The error messages appear in the crawler log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be several things:

1. The following tag in the html:

> 

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

2. An entry in the robots.txt file blocking the crawler
3. An Authentication problem blocking access to content